# Tabulate k = 2^n minimizing multiplication

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Given the following problem:

```
;3.3 Tabulate the function k = 2^n for n = 1..50. 
;Do this for the fewest possible multiplications.[3]
```

I wrote this answer:

```
(defun k (n) (ash 2 (1- n)))

(loop for n from 1 to 50 do
      (format t "k(~a) = ~a ~%" n (k n)))
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `1` instead of `2` as the number to shift, you won't have to subtract one from `n`. I.e. you can just define `k` as `(ash 1 n)`.

Other than that your code looks fine.